# CRUD with Many to Many relationships in Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have two models and one join table.
I would like to use the same view to edit and create new purchase order while adding items in the same form.

PurchaseOrder Model:

```
public class PurchaseOrder
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Requester { get; set; }

    public int WorkOrder { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string WorkSite { get; set; }

    public string Equipment { get; set; }

    public string Operator { get; set; }

    public string Remarks { get; set; }

    public ICollection<PurchaseOrderItem> Items { get; set; }
}
```

Item Model:

```
public class Item
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }

        public string PartNumber { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int Quantity { get; set; }

    public string Remarks { get; set; }

    public ICollection<PurchaseOrderItem> PurchaseOrders { get; set; }
}
```

Join Table Entity

```
    public class PurchaseOrderItem
{
    public int PurchaseOrderID { get; set; }
    public int ItemID { get; set; }
    public PurchaseOrder PurchaseOrder { get; set; }
    public Item Item { get; set; }
}
```

PurchaseOrdersController Edit:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            var purchaseOrder = await _context.PurchaseOrders
                .Include(x => x.Items)
                    .ThenInclude(x => x.Item)
                .Where(x => x.ID == id)
                .AsNoTracking()
                .SingleOrDefaultAsync();

            if (purchaseOrder == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return View(purchaseOrder);
        }
```

Edit Post Method:

```
[HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int id, PurchaseOrder order)
        {
            if (id != order.ID)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                try
                {
                    var po = _context.PurchaseOrders.FirstOrDefault(i => i.ID == order.ID);
                    po.Requester = order.Requester;
                    po.WorkOrder = order.WorkOrder;
                    po.WorkSite = order.WorkSite;
                    po.Equipment = order.Equipment;
                    po.Operator = order.Operator;
                    po.Remarks = order.Remarks;

                    _context.Update(po);

                    

                    foreach (var i in order.Items)
                    {
                        var item = _context.Items.FirstOrDefault(n => n.ID == i.Item.ID);
                        item.PartNumber = i.Item.PartNumber;
                        item.Name = i.Item.Name;
                        item.Description = i.Item.Description;
                        item.Quantity = i.Item.Quantity;
                        item.Remarks = i.Item.Remarks;

                        _context.Update(item);
                    }

                    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                }
                catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
                {

                    if (!PurchaseOrderExists(order.ID))
                    {
                        return NotFound();

                    }

                    else
                    {
                        throw;
                    }
                }
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
            }

            return View(order);

        }
```

Edit View

```html
@model OrderTrackingApp.Models.PurchaseOrder

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Edit";
}

<h1>Edit</h1>

<h4>PurchaseOrder</h4>
<hr />
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form asp-action="Edit">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <input type="hidden" asp-for="ID" />
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Requester" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Requester" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Requester" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="WorkOrder" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="WorkOrder" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="WorkOrder" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="WorkSite" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="WorkSite" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="WorkSite" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Equipment" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Equipment" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Equipment" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Operator" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Operator" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Operator" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Remarks" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Remarks" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Remarks" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label">Order Items</label>
                <table>
                    <tbody>
                        @{ int i = 0;}
                        <tr>
                            @foreach (var OrderItem in Model.Items)
                            {
                                <td>
                                    <input type="hidden" value="OrderItem[@i].ItemID" asp-for="@OrderItem.ItemID"
                                           class="form-control" />
                                    <input type="text" value="OrderItem[@i].Item.PartNumber" asp-for="@OrderItem.Item.PartNumber" class="form-control" />
                                    <input type="text" value="OrderItem[@i].Item.Name" asp-for="@OrderItem.Item.Name" />
                                </td>
                                i++;
                            }
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>


        </form>

    </div>
</div>

    


<div>
    <a asp-action="Index">Back to List</a>
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}
}
```

I have two problems currently with the Edit:

- The label for the item populates as follows: OrderItem[0].Item.Name instead of Value
- When the code reaches the foreachloop to iterate over items, it is throwing a null exception.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting name only as for newly added child items, you don't have ids. and getting null values as in returned data for relational table ids of child data are not initialized.

you can solve this issue in tow ways as per suitability:

- Add child rows from view directly and update ids in model, so you
  will always have ids in data and you will not need face null ids
  issue.
- Alternatively, You may need to add new values of child table first
  then use new ids in relational data manually before saving changes.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is model binding, it is based on the name attribute. Change the code like below:

```
@{ int i = 0;}
<tr>
    @foreach (var OrderItem in Model.Items)
    {
        <td>
            <input type="hidden" name="Items[@i].Item.ID" asp-for="@OrderItem.Item.ID"
                    class="form-control" />
            <input type="text" name="Items[@i].Item.PartNumber" asp-for="@OrderItem.Item.PartNumber" class="form-control" />
            <input type="text" name="Items[@i].Item.Name" asp-for="@OrderItem.Item.Name" class="form-control" />
        </td>
        i++;
    }
</tr>
```